# How to reset Disqus within Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, disqus

I'm running a Wordpress site with the Disqus plugin and I have decided to load in blog posts using ajax. I had read that ajax would break the disqus system, but they came out with a reset function to handle that.

I just can't figure out how to implement this reset function to make this work. Here is the link to the reset function: [DISQUS.reset](http://docs.disqus.com/help/85/). The one difference is that my site is not using hashbangs but I emailed Disqus support and they assured me this was not an issue.

Alternatively, I've tried to implement the Disqus Universal code on my single post page template (as suggested in another thread) but I'm still having no luck. If I reload the page normally, Disqus will load with the correct thread, so I know my universal code is working.

Anyone have a similar issue? Thanks!

Comment: I spoke again with Disqus support and they were unable to provide an answer and suggested I post here. I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: I was going through the same trouble, and like n'verba said below, I just changed the settings to NOT use 2012 version and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the newer Disqus 2012 release, this does not support the DISQUS.reset function as of yet. Developers are advised to stick with the older version, (configurable in the Disqus admin settings.)

[See the 2012 release notes](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-disqus-2012-and-f-a-q-)

Update:  This answer is outdated as Disqus now supports DISQUS.reset.

Comment: Why is not mentioned anywhere in the docs? I've spent last three full days trying to make this work (plus a day off because I felt too stressed out and demotivated since I couldn't make this one simple thing work), thinking it was me who was wrong. After seeing this I just changed the setting and it immediately starts working.Simply stating this on your Ajax help page would have been enough. You can never imagine how much stress I went through because of this.

Comment: I agree, it should be more obvious. Especially as new accounts are on 2012 by default and the official documentation still shows the DISQUS.reset.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, could you accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm not the one who asked the question, although I was going through the same problem and am thankful that it helped me. Hope the OP accepts it!

Comment: Oops!, that's what I get for not paying attention. I'm glad it helped, I lost the best part of a day to this also.

Comment: ah I first thought you were working at Disqus, sorry for complaining to you :)

Comment: I've wasted the last 2 hours trying to figure out why DISQUS.reset isn't even in the DOM. Thank you.